# How to not print cmd output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I try to run this code

```
import os
path_a = r'D:\Prroject'

if os.system("cd " + path_a) == 1:
    print("Invalid Path!")
else:
    print("Valid Path!")
```

and get ouput

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
Invalid Path!
```

how to remove the "`The system cannot find the path specified.`" and make the output only print "`Invalid Path!`" .

Comment: The `os` module has a function for changing directory https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir `os.chdir(path_a)`

Comment: Use `os.chdir()` for that. Also calling `cd` doesn't even work properly when you're changing path across different drive letters, and it's baked into `cmd.exe` so I'm surprised it even does something, it probably won't work at all unless you run python from a command prompt.

Comment: using cmd.exe makes me feel dirty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should really use the os module for this, here's a potential approach:

```
try:
    os.chdir('doesntexist')
    print('Valid Path!')
except:
    print('Invalid Path!')
```

output:

```
Invalid Path!
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the standard error output to /dev/null.

```
os.system("cd " + path_a + " 2>/dev/null")
```

This syntax works with bash-type shells; if you use a different shell, consult that shell's manual.

However, you should be aware that running `cd` from `os.system()` is very likely to be useless, as the changed directory only persists for the lifetime of the `os.system()` call, which is very short.  The next time you run a `os.system()` command, you will be back in the original directory.